# Bootstrap keep background visible all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So id like to keep my background image visible behind all my content but as I'm adding in new stuff it adds a white background... Is there a way around this below is my code for my site, I have added a logo and the whole section has gone white behind.

[image]

```css
/*!
Main Page CSS || Created By Thomas Withers @ Ice7Media
 */

/* Global Styles
============================================================ */
html { 
  background: url(../img/GreyWeavePaper-Portrait.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 80px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
    font-family: 'Oswald', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

/* Global Navbar Formatting
==============================================================*/

.navbar {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.navbar ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar.transparent.navbar-default {
    border-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 0.00%, 50.00% 100.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
}

/* Global Footer Formatting
==============================================================*/
/* Home Page Formatting
==============================================================*/
/*Full Width Slider Formatting */
/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
    height: 10%;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 16px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 16px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 16px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color:#bbb;
}
.carousel img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Menu's Page Formatting
==============================================================*/
/* E-Club Page Formatting
==============================================================*/
/* Events Page Formatting
==============================================================*/
/* Contact Page Formatting
==============================================================*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<!-- Meta charset 
===================================================================================-->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        
<!-- Title  
===================================================================================-->
        <title>Bocaditio | South Amercian Dishes</title>
        
<!-- Meta Tags  
===================================================================================-->
        <meta name="author" content="Thomas Withers @ Ice7Media">
        <meta name="description" content="Social Media Wizzards that handle all of your social media markerting.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

        <!-- CSS Stylesheets  
===================================================================================-->
        <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/Custom.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/Mapstyle.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/iceBox.png">
        
<!-- Custom Fonts 
===================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

<!-- Navigation
===================================================================================-->
 <div class = "navbar transparent navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class = "container">
   <a href = "index" class = "navbar-brand">
            <img src="img/BocaditoLogo.png">
            </a>
   <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
            
   <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                
    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "about.html">Menus</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "e-clubs.html">E-Clubs</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- Full screen Slider    
===================================================================================--> 
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="/img/Outside.jpg" class="fill">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="/img/Bar.jpg" class="fill">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="/img/Table_1.jpg" class="fill">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="/img/Tables_2.jpg" class="fill">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
      </a>  
    </div>
    <!-- /.carousel -->
<!-- Abouts Us & Logo
===================================================================================--> 
    <section class="logo" id="logo">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img src="img/BocaditoLogo.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<!-- Top Dishes
===================================================================================-->
<!-- footer
===================================================================================-->
<!-- Scripts
===================================================================================-->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC22aNgIjcYzx5Oel1m0Jtcem-W4R895fQ"></script>
    <!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The background in the logo image is not transparent; if you make it transparent, then it won't show the white...

Comment: Yes it is transparent.. Its the same image I use in the navbar and I put it into Photoshop to make it transparent

Comment: Can anyone help please still have this problem....

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
background: url(../img/GreyWeavePaper-Portrait.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

this under body {   }

```
body {
   background: url(../img/GreyWeavePaper-Portrait.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin-top: 80px;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   color: #000;
}
```

Comment: This works but make the image zoomed and horrible...   https://i.gyazo.com/20b5303b87fac4ba5db4d6573333e323.png